# Properties of infinitely differentiable functions with compact support

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $\phi\in C_c^{\infty}(B_r)$ be a nonnegative function where $B_r=B_r(x_0)$ be a ball of radius $r$ centered at $x_0$. Let $p>2$, then is it possible to write the following inequality:
$$
|\phi^p(x)-\phi^p(y)|\leq C|\phi(x)-\phi(y)|^p
$$
for some positive constant $C$. Here $C_c^{\infty}(B_r)$ denotes the set of infinitely differentiable functions with compact support in $B_r$.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanking you.

Comment: The RHS is shift invariant, what shift makes the LHS maximum

Comment: I did not get, can you kindly elaborate the answer? Is it true?

Comment: @reuns Huh? I don't follow any of what you  said...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Let $b=\|\phi\|_\infty$, replace $\phi$ by $\phi+a$, the RHS stays the same, the LHS grows, attaining its maximum at when one of $\phi(x),\phi(y)$ is $b$, thus we are left with $b^p-(b-h)^p\le C_{b,p} h^p$ which is true only for $p=1$

Comment: @reuns But if $\phi\in C^\infty_c$ it seems hard to show that $\phi+a\in C^\infty_c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with $C^\infty_c$; the question is just whether $$|s^p-t^p|\le C|s-t|^p$$for $s,t\ge0$.

The answer is no. For small $h>0$ the binomial theorem or just a little calculus shows that$$(1+h)^p-1^p\sim ph >> h^p.$$